# Low Side N-Channel 75V to 12V Buck Converter with feedback

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck, converter

I want to design a buck converter for E-bike with 75V input and 12V, 20A (240W ideal case) output to drive the other components of E-bike using n-mosfet as a low side.

I also want to use a feedback using a microcontroller to adjust the output voltage to 12V when the load vary. If anyone could help me and guide me in the design as I’m new to this?

Comment: What are the other 12 V components, that need 240 W in an E-bike? Have a look at LM5145.

Comment: 12V component doesn't need 240W, motor driver IC such as IR2112 for example need 12V, and other bike components such as lights, horn, digital meter and any controller if used would require 12V.